# PHPUnit error while creating unit test cases

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

i have controller class `"UserController"`(in controller folder) which extends `BaseController` (present in app folder),

when i right click and select option `"Create PHPUnitTests"` it gives me following error:

```
phpunit Fatal error: Class 'Base Controller' not found
```

can ayone tell me  why i get this error and what i have to configure for the same.
I using custom php framework

Comment: netbeans? is your framework in your IDE include-path? tried to edit the UserController an `include` the BaseController` by hand? `include_once('path/to/BaseController.php');`

Comment: i added the include path in bootstrap.php so that it can be available globally for other controllers also 

And That is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Include Path is likely not configured correctly for your IDE. For Netbeans, follow the instructions given in the Netbeans User Manual:

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#phpIncludePath

If you are not using `include` statements to include the files to be tested in the UnitTests, you also have to bootstrap the environment. Executing the UnitTests from the IDE will likely not run your regular bootstrap file. Consider adding a phpunit.xml file to your tests:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     <!--bootstrap="/path/to/bootstrap.php"-->
     colors="false"
     …
<php>
    <includePath>.</includePath>
```

See the Appendix in the PHPUnit Manual for more information:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Follow the instructions given in the Netbeans User Manual to make the IDE consider the file automatically when tests are run:

- http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/recent_improvements_in_phpunit_support